# How can I need to de-transformation from diff(log(data),1)?

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation

I applied ARIMA to a time-series dataset (`dataset`).

In order to archive stationary, I applied the following steps:

1. log transformation `log_dataset <- log(dataset)`
2. `difflog_dataset <- diff(log_dataset,1)` to my dataset.
3. I tested stationary by Ljung-Box.

I fitted `difflog_dataset` by ARIMA(1,0,2) adequately.

`fit <- Arima(difflog_dataset, order=c(1,0,2))`

Do I need to de-transformation from `fitted(fit)` to get $\hat{y}$ value? How can I do that ?

Comment: The inverse operation of differentiation is integration. Or, for your discrete problem the cumulative sum, i.e., R function `cumsum`. However, differentiation is not lossless: you lose any information about an offset (a constant). Are you doing forecasting?

Comment: You may use ARIMA(1,1,2) that is equivalent to diff(log_dataset,1), as 1 in the middle, roughly speaking, states for the difference order. Then just apply exp($\hat{y}$) in order to get right values.

Comment: @Roland. Yes, I'm using time series for forecasting.

Comment: Why did you feel it was necessary to take logs in the first place   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers . Differencing a series to deal with a form of non-stationarity is one thing taking a power transform is often unwarranted http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation ...slide 61-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say your original series is $y_t$ and you define the transformed series:

$$\tilde{y}_t = \log(y_t)-\log(y_{t-1})$$

You then forecast the value of $\tilde{y}_{t+1}$ by using your ARIMA(1,0,2) model, giving you $\hat{\tilde{y}}_{t+1}$, but you want a forecast of $y_{t+1}$. You can compute it like this:

$$\hat{y}_{t+1} = y_t \exp\left({\hat{\tilde{y}}_{t+1}}\right)$$

More generally, you can verify that the following telescoping sum:

$$\log(y_t) = \log(y_0) + \sum_{i=1}^t \left(\log(y_i)-\log(y_{i-1})\right)$$

implies that the inverse transformation is:

$$y_t = y_0 \exp{\left(\sum_{i=1}^t \tilde{y}_i\right)}$$

As a practical matter, the `forecast::Arima` function you are using will do all of this for you if you specify both the log-transform and the difference in the function call, instead of doing it by hand before calling it:

```
fit <- Arima(dataset, order=c(1,1,2), lambda=0)
```